# Image of a quadratic form is a closed cone

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, quadratic-forms, vector-spaces, cones

Let $Q : E \to F$ be a quadratic form induced by a symmetric bilinear form $B : E \times E \to F$ defined in a finite dimensional real normed vector space $E$, with values in the normed vector space $F \supseteq E$ (continuous inclusion). I already know that the image $C= Q(E)$ is a cone in $F$. How do I prove that it is also closed? Also, is it true that the convex hull of $C$ is closed?

Comment: Really? Do you have a counterexample in mind? What if the norms are induced by an inner product?

Comment: I'll post a counterexample. But in fact, I'm quite confused about the convexity now. (Probably because I should actually sleep rather than doing maths...)

Comment: May I ask whether you found out whether $Q(E)$ is always convex?

Comment: I didn't found out :( but I suspect it may not be always convex

Comment: Thanks for your response!

Comment: Today I happened to find a simple counterexample which shows that $Q(E)$ is not always convex: let $E = \mathbb{R}^2$ and $F = \mathbb{R}^{2 \times 2}$, and let $B(x,y) = xy^{\operatorname{T}}$ for all $x,y \in E$. Then the range of $Q$ is the set of the symmetric matrices of rank $\le 1$, which is not convex.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general, $Q(E)$ is not closed.

**Counterexample.** Let $E = F = \mathbb{R}^2$ and set
$$
  B(x,y) := 
  \begin{pmatrix}
    x_1y_1 \\
    x_1y_2 + x_2y_1
  \end{pmatrix}.
$$
Then
$$
  Q(x) := 
  \begin{pmatrix}
    x_1^2 \\ 2x_1x_2
  \end{pmatrix},
$$
so $Q(E)$ is the open right half plane together with the origin.